# Django tutorial 8 pip install Errno 1

Tags: python, django, pip

Hello I am following the [Django tutorial 8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/reusable-apps/) but then I reach the point where I must `pip install --user django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz` I get the error

> Processing path\django-polls\dist\django-polls-0.1.tar.gz
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "c:\users\Name\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\tokenize.py", line 452, in open
>           buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
>       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uqc76lp7-build\setup.py'
>   Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uqc76lp7-build\

I have tried to update `pip`, `setuptools`, `easyinstall` but nothing is working I still get the error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: @anmaxvl I am guessing not since i don't know what that is. I am not a very advanced programer

Comment: Is that the entire error message? If not, please post all of it.

Comment: If you're new to Python, it would be a good idea to learn about virtual environments (it's probably even more useful than learning about re-usable packages). The [Django Girls tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_installation/#virtual-environment) uses virtual environments to install Django, you might find that part useful. For now, if you're not using a virtual environment, then you might need to install your package with pip3 (Python 3) instead of pip (Python 2).

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks I tryed pip3 with the same error message. I also updated the question to show the full error message. I will try and follow the tutorial you suggested and see how it goes.